# Not able to import git android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I tried several times to import [this git repos](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) into my eclipse and run it as android application, but no success.

Can someone please suggest me how to import it in correct manner.

Comment: R u not able to import or not able to run?

Comment: ok then see the ans and try the third point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try these things:

- Check whether is a same mane project existing in your eclipse work-space?
- Restart eclipse and then try the same
- Import project as existing android code not as existing project

**Steps** : **Import-> Existing android code into workspace -> Also mark copy into workspace-> Done**

If there is not visible option of copy into workspace then probably there is already similar name project into workspace. First delete that and try the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **Clone in Desktop** or **Download Zip**.

Then from Eclipse, **Import > Existing projects into Workspace**.

Hope it work.